# HTML Agility Pack Causing High Memory Usage In Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, html-agility-pack, asp.net-blazor

Through analyzing the memory of my application Blazor app using a Class Library which crawls over several (potentially hundreds) of links gathering data on the sites. I noticed that through each action the user was taking (which initiates HTML agility pack to start processing sites) the memory was growing and never going down. After digging in a bit, I narrowed the issue down to where the HTMLDocument nodes were being created (using web.load(site)). I took a couple of memory snapshots before and after the user interaction, and it appears as though the HTMLDocumnets, HTMLNodeCollections, HTMLNOded, etc... are not being garbage collected and are remaining in memory. I'm not sure if this is something I am doing incorrectly with the agility pack as I am new to this library, or if there is something else I am missing.

below is a simplified code snippet where the problem is occuring. It is worth noting, although not relevant to the problem that this is using a semaphore to throttle the number of links that the app will attempt to crawl at any given time.
`

```
List<Task> throttledTasks = new List<Task>();
            List<HtmlDocument> docs = new List<HtmlDocument>();
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            foreach (var link in bracketLinks)
            {
                throttledTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await ssThrottle.WaitAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(link);
                        if (doc is not null)
                        {
                            docs.Add(doc);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ssThrottle.Release();
                    }
                }));
            }
```

`

I've attempted to manually run garbage collection, but that does not seem to help, although I would expect system GC to work properly without the need to manually call GC.Collect().

Update1: It is worth noting that the work-horse that uses HTML Agility Pack is in a class library which Blazor Server is using. To verify that this was not an issue with Blazer Server, I created a console application utilizing the same class library and called the same functions that the web app was. what I found is that GC seemed to be working (at least better than Blazor server) in that the memory actually went down after GC (as opposed to Blazor server which simply kept climbing). To note, the memory was being analyzed by the memory profiler in Release mode. This appears to be a memory issue with Blazor server instead of a direct memory issue with HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that the high memory usage was NOT due to HTML Agility pack. After seeing the way the app memory behaved in a console application, I was confident the issue was with Blazor Server. I did a bit more digging and discovered the server vs workstation garbage collection settings as noted in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector#workstation-vs-server). After setting this to false, the memory behaved much more appropriately and garbage collection appeared to be cleaning objects up as I originally expected it to. To set the garbage collection to run as a workstation, simply add the following setting to your "PropertyGroup" settings in your project file:

```
<ServerGarbageCollection>false</ServerGarbageCollection>
```

[screenshot of ServerGarbageCollection config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON3Kr.png)